# Googlemap Javascript error

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm getting the 'Oops! Something went wrong' message when trying to run this Googlemap. The map code worked fine when I was developing it in isolation (see 'mymap.php' file below), but it's only after I have integrated it into my html template that this has happened. I've tried moving it around and running the javascript both inside and outside the head tags but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
I thought it might be an issue with the API key, but seeing as it works fine in the 'mymap.php' file I reckon that mustn't be it.
Could it be with the fact that I have placed the Javascript to create the map into the head tag? Or is the Bootstrap header maybe interfering in some way?

mymap.php (which works fine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("functions/functions.php");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","lstest1");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>

<?php

if (isset ($_GET['loc_value'])) {
    $locations = array(); // empty array to store location information
    $county = $_GET['loc_value']; // which county are we going to map
    $get_county = "select * from locations where county='$county'";
    $result = $conn->query($get_county);
    while ($row_locations = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $loc_name = $row_locations['loc_name'];
        $latitude = $row_locations['latitude'];
        $longitude = $row_locations['longitude'];
        $description = $row_locations['loc_desc'];

        $newLocation = array ("title" => $loc_name, "lat" => $latitude, "lng" => $longitude, "description" => $description);
        array_push($locations, $newLocation);
    }//while
}//if
//print_r($locations);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;


window.onload = function() {
        LoadMap();
    }

function LoadMap() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.6990782, -6.6171596),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


     for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var data = locations[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
        }
}//loadmap
</script>


<div class="map-responsive" id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

This is it placed within the Bootstrap template I am using - filename 'countymap.php':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("functions/functions.php");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","lstest1");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>

<?php

if (isset ($_GET['loc_value'])) {
    $locations = array(); // empty array to store location information
    $county = $_GET['loc_value']; // which county are we going to map
    $get_county = "select * from locations where county='$county'";
    $result = $conn->query($get_county);
    while ($row_locations = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $loc_name = $row_locations['loc_name'];
        $latitude = $row_locations['latitude'];
        $longitude = $row_locations['longitude'];
        $description = $row_locations['loc_desc'];

        $newLocation = array ("title" => $loc_name, "lat" => $latitude, "lng" => $longitude, "description" => $description);
        array_push($locations, $newLocation);
    }//while
}//if
//print_r($locations);
?>


<html lang="en">

    <!-- Arvo font for webpage & font-awesome-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stoke' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<head>
  <title>Location Scout</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="styles/location.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Map</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;


window.onload = function() {
        LoadMap();
    }

function LoadMap() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.6990782, -6.6171596),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


     for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var data = locations[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
        }
}//loadmap
</script>

</head>

<body>


<div class="container-fluid text-center">

<!-- MAIN HEADING AREA -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>
                LOCATION SCOUT
            </h1>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- MAIN ACTIVITY WINDOW -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">

        <div class="map-responsive" id="map" ;"></div>

        </div>


        <!-- SIDEBAR/MENU AREA -->

        <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Homepage</a>
<a href="user_home.php?user" class="btn btn-success" role="button">User Page</a>

</div>

        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

           <div class="form col-md-3">
                            <form method="get" action="results.php">
                                <input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="Search for location"/>

                              <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"/>

                                </form>
                            </div>
    </div>
</div>


            <h2>Welcome!</h2>

            <p>
                This is your one-stop shop to plan your visit to some of Northern Ireland's most fascinating movie and Tv locations.
                Start your search on the menus below or use the search box above to get plotting!
            </p>

            <h2>Start your search:</h2>

            <div class="btn-group">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">By County</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                <a href="getCounty.php?county=Antrim">Antrim</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getCounty.php?county=Armagh">Armagh</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getCounty.php?county=Down">Down</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getCounty.php?county=Fermanagh">Fermanagh</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getCounty.php?county=Londonderry">Londonderry</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getCounty.php?county=Tyrone">Tyrone</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><br>
            <div><br></div>
            <div class="btn-group">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">By Genre</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="getGenre.php?genre=Drama">Drama</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getGenre.php?genre=Thriller">Thriller</a>
                </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getGenre.php?genre=Documentary">Documentary</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getGenre.php?genre=Horror">Horror</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getGenre.php?genre=Sci-fi">Sci-fi</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getGenre.php?genre=Children">Children</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getGenre.php?genre=Fantasy">Fantasy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><br>
            <div><br></div>
            <div class="btn-group">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">By Production</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="getProduction.php?production=Game of Thrones">Game of Thrones</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getProduction.php?production=Line of Duty">Line of Duty</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="getProduction.php?production=The Fall">The Fall</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><br>
            <div><br></div>

            <div class="btn-group">

            <a href="login.php?login" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Login</a>
            <a href="registration.php?registration" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Register</a>
            </div><br>
            <br><div class="btn-group">
            <a href="Admin_area/index.php" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Admin</a>
                    </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```